# Multiple Linq functions as parameter

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method which searchs Items in the Database. Because I use it multiple times I made it generic:

```
public async Task Search(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria, Func<T, object> order)
{
    return Task.Run(async () => Searchlist.AddRange((await Service.SearchAsync(criteria, false)).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(order)));
}
```

Because it is generic, I implement the parameter order, that they are ordered correctly. I call the method like this:

```
await Search(GetCriteria(), p => p.Description);
```

But I have some objects which are ordered by multiple (between 2 and 4) properties. So they are ordered like this:

```
SearchAsync(criteria, false)).AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(y => y.Nr).ThenBy(z => z.Type))
```

Can I create a parameter where I can put the Methods to call. Like `.OrderBy(x => x.Date).ThenBy(y => y.Nr).ThenBy(z => z.Type)` or only `.OrderBy(x => x.Date)`.

Thanks

Comment: Don't await the Task.Run in the search method. _`await Task.Run(async ()`_ The caller can determine if it want to  await it or maybe await multiple Tasks. Just return the Task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to break the current interface of your function, go with:

```
public async Task Search(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria, Func<T, object>[] order)
{
    var elems = await Service.SearchAsync(criteria, false);
    var sorted = elems.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(order.First());
    foreach(var subOrder in order.Skip(1)){
      sorted = sorted.ThenBy(subOrder);
    }
    Searchlist.AddRange(sorted)
}

await Search(GetCriteria(), new []{p => p.Date, p => p.Description});
```

If you dont want to break the current interface, go with:

```
public async Task Search(
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria, 
   Func<T, object> mainOrder, 
   params Func<T, object>[] subOrders)
{
    var elems = await Service.SearchAsync(criteria, false);
    var sorted = elems.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(mainOrder);
    foreach(var subOrder in subOrders){
      sorted = sorted.ThenBy(subOrder);
    }
    Searchlist.AddRange(sorted)
}

await Search(GetCriteria(), p => p.Date, p => p.Description);
```